# ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vscode-extensions, google-cloud-run

I'm getting this error when trying to deploy on **Google Cloud Run** using **VS Code** with the **Google Cloud Code** extension. How can I solve this?

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy)
> spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value
> specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale may not exceed
> 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I didn't find a solution via the UI, it can be solved via the command line in this way:

```
gcloud run deploy ... --max-instances 10
```

It seems the default value for maxScale (max-instances) is 100.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the default value is 100. Just to add more information [from the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/max-instances#limits) in case other people encounters the error:

> By default, Cloud Run services are configured to a maximum of 100 instances
>
> The maximum limit depends on the region of the Cloud Run service and its CPU and memory configurations.
>
> The [quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=run.googleapis.com&usage=ALL&_ga=2.42261541.181621500.1710166015-2016808172.1703016005&_gac=1.225078120.1708338359.CjwKCAiAlcyuBhBnEiwAOGZ2S4d-riGGaQAIDWFDcUJO5jVuAHSNf51jht4exJnXb1cF4kpPa7JFAxoCLcIQAvD_BwE) shows the baseline quotas per-region.
>
> The maximum number of instances is determined as the minimum of:
>
> - regional quota baseline / requested multiple of 1 CPU
> - regional quota baseline / requested multiple of 2GB memory
>
> For example, a baseline quota of 1000 instances with either 4GB memory or 2 CPU will get an effective limit of 500.
>
> If you want to specify a maximum number of instances greater than the maximum allowed in the region of the Cloud Run service, you must [request a quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#increase).

Then, [from this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/max-instances#viewing), they can check their current maximum instances settings.